# jQuery .removeClass() - doesn't remove the class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove a class, but it fails from some reason, can anyone share some ideas ?

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if ($('.space-fill').height() > 22) {
         $('.space-fill').addClass('space-full');
    }
    else{
         $('.space-fill').removeClass('space-full');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your class name `space-fill` or `space-full`?

Comment: .space-fill is the main class and I need to add a second class to it, in order to make it red.

Comment: How does it "fail"? How many `.space-fill` elements do you have? `$('.space-fill').height()` will only return the height of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a wild guess and say that you have to iterate over all `.space-fill` elements in order to read their height and apply the class:

```
$('.space-fill').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('space-full', $(this).height() > 22);
});
```

Comment: @Axente: You're welcome :) You should then mark this answer as accepted (click the green checkmark next to it), to also mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement, you need to make sure you're comparing apples with apples.

`parseInt($('.space-fill').height()) > 22`

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/): *"The difference between `.css('height')` and `.height()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`)."*

Comment: I'm trying to make a progress bar, the height of the bar is 30px so if the bar is under the 22px mark the bar is blue, else > 22 , the bar turns out red, witch means you are close to exceed your space limit in my project.

Comment: Oh, in case someone did not understand my comment: `.height()` already returns an integer.